# How to limit a log-file to last N lines?

Tags: shell, logging

I have a `./program` which outputs lots of logging messages and also having very limited storage space on my VPS:

> I would like my log-file to contain *only the latest N lines* **all the time** (or rather when I terminate <kbd>^C</kbd> my program **or when it crashes...**)

### A. I do *not* want the following:

1. *"Redirect the output to a (log-)file and then use `tail` to keep only the last N lines."*

   Well the log-file would still take precious take space until I run `tail` on it, which makes it pointless... I can set a cronjob up to do it periodically if I have no other choice, but I'd like to explore the possibilities first.
2. "Use [`logrotate`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-logfiles-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-16-04)."

   `logrotate` seems to be the proper solution to the problem, but it's too much of an hassle and I want something simpler, preferably something I can do with pipes and redirections.

### B. I have tried the following:

(replaced `./program` with `seq 1000000` if for testing)

1. `seq 1000000 | tee /dev/fd/2 | tail -n 10 > logfile`

   Works perfectly fine when it terminates on its own, but when I interrupt <kbd>^C</kbd> it myself, the `logfile` is empty (whereas I expect it to contain last 10 lines that are printed on the screen by `tee`)
2. `mkfifo fifo; tail fifo -n 10 > logfile & seq 1000000 | tee fifo`

   Works perfectly fine when it terminates on its own, but when I interrupt <kbd>^C</kbd> it myself, the `logfile` is **not** empty, **but** also does not contain a bit of latest log entries that are printed on the screen:

.

```
$ tail fifo -n 10 > logfile & seq 1000000 | tee fifo
[1] 2616
1
2
3
⋮
480178
480179
480180
480181
480182
480183
^C
[1]+  Done                    tail fifo -n 10 > logfile
$ cat logfile
479297
479298
479299
479300
479301
479302
479303
479304
479305
```

Here you can see that the latest entries are at 480 thousands, whereas the latest entry in the `logfile` is 479,305... meaning I miss 878 latest lines! I think this has something to do with buffering but I am not sure.

Can someone show me how to do this using only shell and (preferably standard) Linux utilities? Thanks!

Comment: Personally I use a cron that runs everyday at 12:12:12 am to purge log files... since they are pruned to size daily they never get big, that cron  generates some html to a file that gets included in a personal status page (mix of php and html) that lets me quickly keep an eye on things.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution for your case is probably circular log, that has fixed size.

If you are on Linux, you can try kernel module [`emlog`](https://github.com/nicupavel/emlog)

> The emlog kernel module implements simple character device driver. The driver acts like a named pipe that has a finite, circular buffer. The size of the buffer is easily configurable. As more data is written into the buffer, the oldest data is discarded. A process that reads from an emlog device will first read the existing buffer, then see new text as it's written, similar to monitoring a log file using "tail -f". (Non-blocking reads are also supported, if a process needs to get the current contents of the log without blocking to wait for new data.)

On BSD systems see `CLOG(8)`